# Does anyone know how I can embed Vue component/Project into Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, vue-component, angular1.6

I have spent some time on this. I have an HUGE Angular JS project ( Angular 1.6.5). I would like to move some components into Vue.

First thing we came across is Web Components: but AngularJS application must be on version 1.7.3 or higher.
We explored ngVue library  but :    . To use this https://www.nodenpm.com/ngVue/0.1.0/detail.html library in AngularJS, your application must be on version 1.7.9 or higher.

We have vue-custom-component which seems like basically wrapper to web components itself.

We are left with iframe, which we know works  from the start but we were trying to avoid it.

Has anyone tried such thing already? Do we know of any other alternative library we can use to achieve the benefits of web-components in angularjs 1.6.
Thank you in advanc

Comment: This could well be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731) - could you give some context on _why_ you want to move components into Vue?

Comment: Basically it's `new Vue...mount` in `$postLink` and `unmount` in `$onDestroy`. Unless you want it to interact with ng app, it's that simple. If it's Vue 2, ngVue fits the case. *your application must be on version 1.7.9 or higher* - where did you get this from? The library is several years old. Even if current version wouldn't work with 1.6, others would.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you for response. It is mentioned in https://www.nodenpm.com/ngVue/0.1.0/detail.html down at dependency section. we did not try older versions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is part of larger initative to migrate from AngularJs to Vue by replacing features into creating Vue microfrontends

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of data this site provides. I assume it's just wrong. The package doesn't have a restriction, https://github.com/ngVue/ngVue/blob/master/package.json#L27 . Even if it would have it, it could be downgraded.

Comment: As far as I know there is no reason you can't use an older version of AngularJS. The angular dev dependency is only for the examples app. Way late to  this question but maybe helpful to someone in the future. (I am a maintainer of this package.)